# How to solve 'Fatal: Invalid date format' in terminal (git)

Tags: git, macos, date, github, terminal

I have an issue where I keep getting an error message as below:

```
$ git commit -m "Update"
fatal: invalid date format: -7 -8 12:3:00
```

whenever I try to commit to or clone from a github repository - using my terminal (MacOS).

To attempt to change my date format to a 'valid' one,
I have tried running commands like:

```
$ git commit --date="2020-07-11"

$ GIT_COMMITER_DATE="date" git commit --amend --no-edit --date "date"
```

and also tried changing date format to relative time:

```
$ git commit -m "Test" --date=format:relative:3.hours.ago
```

But none of these commands, including many others, work; I keep getting the same message, 'fatal: invalid date format:...'.
Currently, I am unable to commit, push, nor clone my repositories on github.

If anyone has encountered a similar problem, I would absolutely love any help/advice on this issue, thanks so much.

Comment: Hi there, just in case it's important, what software are you using that you are trying to commit to GitHub?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Likely source of the error message: https://github.com/git/git/blob/bd42bbe1a46c0fe486fc33e82969275e27e4dc19/ident.c#L436

Your environment (which is managed by your shell) includes `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` or `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` (or both) with an invalid value (likely `-7 -8 12:3:00`). You probably ran something like the following commands:

```
$ export GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="-7 -8 12:3:00"
$ export GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="-7 -8 12:3:00"
```

Fix the problem by removing `GIT_AUTHOR_DATE` and `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE` from your shell's environment, allowing Git to fill in a default:

```
$ unset GIT_AUTHOR_DATE
$ unset GIT_COMMITTER_DATE
```

Comment: The git plugin for oh-my-zsh sets one of these automatically. Btw, THANK YOU !!!! You have no idea what Ive been through. The Evs are the only thing I havent grepped. Ive grepped the aliases for git, Ive run git commit 1000 different ways, and I even redirected a grep of my entire `.zsh_history` file (16,000+lines; ~1000 after grep) and went through it line by line, all the way back, not knowing what to do. Cant believe I forgot the EVs. Now I just have to unstash and sort through 3 days worth of changes patch by patch, and Ill be good. THANKS AGAIN!